# How to make Countdown Input with Button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wanna make Countdown Timer with input, start button and stop/reset button. I try to make the input and start button but it does kinda not work, how to fix this problem with the input for the timer that can work?

```js
const daysEl = document.getElementById("days");
const hoursEl = document.getElementById("hours");
const minsEl = document.getElementById("mins");
const secondsEl = document.getElementById("seconds");

const newYears = document.getElementById("Timer").value;

function countdown(){
    const newYearsDate = new Date(newYears);
    const currentDate = new Date();

    const totalSeconds = (newYearsDate - currentDate) / 1000;

    const days = Math.floor(totalSeconds / 3600 / 24);
    const hours = Math.floor(totalSeconds / 3600 ) % 24;
    const mins = Math.floor(totalSeconds / 60) % 60;
    const seconds = Math.floor(totalSeconds) % 60; 

    daysEl.innerHTML = days;
    hoursEl.innerHTML = formatTime(hours);
    minsEl.innerHTML = formatTime(mins);
    secondsEl.innerHTML = formatTime(seconds);
}

function formatTime(time){
    return time < 10 ? `0${time}` : time;
}
// initial call
if(start){
    countdown();
    setInterval(countdown, 1000);
}
else{
    alert("invalid date");
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@200;400;600&display=swap');

*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
    background-image: url("assets/newyear.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-height: 100vh;
    align-items: center;
    font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
}

h1{
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 4rem;
    margin-top: 5rem;
    color: white;
}

.countdown-container{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.big-text{
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 6rem;
    line-height: 1;
    margin: 1rem 2rem;
    color: white;
}

.countdown-el{
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}

.countdown-el span{
    font-size: 1.3rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>CountDown Timer</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="countdowninput">
        <input type="text" id="Timer" value="1 Jan 2023"/>
        <button id="start" type="submit">Start</button>
    </div>
    <h1>New Years Eve</h1>

    <div class="countdown-container">
        <div class="countdown-el days-c">
            <p class="big-text" id="days">0</p>
            <span>days</span>
        </div>
        <div class="countdown-el hours-c">
            <p class="big-text" id="hours">0</p>
            <span>hours</span>
        </div>
        <div class="countdown-el mins-c">
            <p class="big-text" id="mins">0</p>
            <span>minutes</span>
        </div>
        <div class="countdown-el seconds-c">
            <p class="big-text" id="seconds">0</p>
            <span>seconds</span>
        </div>
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

After this maybe I would do change the image button on the timer bottom, like new year, birthday, Christmas, and more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go! Create an input with whatever id you choose, in this case I used #dateSearch.

Create an input value, then create a new Date object from the input value.

Then the rest of the code is what is executing the countdown!

Enjoy.

```js
document.getElementById("dateSearch").addEventListener("change", function() {
    var input = this.value;

var countDownDate = new Date(input).getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

  // Get today's date and time
  var now = new Date().getTime();
    
  // Find the distance between now and the count down date
  var distance = countDownDate - now;
    
  // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
    
  // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
  + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";
    
  // If the count down is over, write some text 
  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
  }
}, 1000);
})
```

```css
#demo {
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-weight: bolder;
  text-align: center;
}

.form-input, h1 {
  text-align: center;
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<div class="form-input">
<label for="dateSearch">Enter a Date to Countdown:</label>
<input type="date" id="dateSearch">
</div>

<div class="countdown">
<h1>Countdown Timer:</h1>
<p id="demo"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: There is some bug when I try the next day, the countdown is good. When I changed it again the countdown error was a bit like blink Nan and blink the countdown.

Comment: @JansenSu thanks for pointing that out, I did not realize that. Let me adjust